# "We should not confuse generalization with [...?...]" (looking for the word that says: it's true for everybody or in any situation)

Tags: antonyms

[Definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/generalization) of generalization:

> A generalization is a statement that seems to be true in most situations or for most people, but that may not be completely true in all cases.

What word would you use to complete this sentence:

> We should not confuse generalization with [... a word telling: it's
>   true for everybody or in any situation]

I'm looking for *a kind of* antonym of `generalization` (or maybe of `mean`, or `probability`, or `common tendency`)

Answer (score 1):

Universality – common to all members of a class

edit: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/universality

Comment: Can you include a dictionary link/citation, please?